# Change prefix key for compose-character (C-x 8)

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys, character-composition

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unibyte-Mode.html), the key `C-x 8` can be used to insert non-ASCII characters. For example, `C-x 8 ' a` will insert "á". Is it possible to change the prefix key to another (shorter) value, like for example, `M-'`? I find `M-'` to be easier to type than `C-x 8`, so this change would make inserting "á", "é", etc. much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on this, and this might not be the right way to do it, but I think this will do it for you:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-'") iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map)))
```

`iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map` is a variable whose value is the keymap I think you're looking for, to bind to `M-'`. `iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map` is the value returned by this:

```
(lookup-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-x 8")))
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I have an additional question though, it there any reason this isn't documented (changing the prefix)? Either I'm the only person that found `C-x 8` to be a bit cumbersome to use, or I'm missing something. I also wasn't able to find my original question anywhere else.

Comment: You can accept the answer, if you think it answers the question. That can help others who have the same question. If you later get a better answer you can change the accepted answer (anytime, any number of times).

Comment: Probably everything about this is documented in the Elisp manual, but it might not be obvious where some of the info is located. Node [Prefix Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html) is one place to start, perhaps. And it helped me to know that I could use `lookup-key` to find what is bound to the key. And somehow I knew or guessed about `key-translation-map`. Node [Translation Keymaps](key-translation-map) talks about that. But you might want to suggest that the manual help more about this: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: A more modern way to accomplish the same is ```(keymap-global-set "M-`" iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map)```.

Since I'm at it, I discovered this while looking for the cause of error "<Multi_key> is undefined" when using Emacs under Xpra. Should you see that same error, the cure is ```(keymap-global-set "<Multi_key>" iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map)```

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use the `Multi_key` (sometimes called the "compose" key) under X11, which I have mapped to the right Alt key.  That works everywhere rather than only in Emacs.

Comment: This seems more like a (useful) comment then an answer to the question. But in a sense it does answer it, telling how to get a compose key for more than just Emacs.

Comment: This worked as well, thanks. I was able to change the behaviour of the right Alt key by going into the GNOME Settings panel -> Keyboards -> Shortcuts -> Typing. I think I'll mark the other answer as accepted because it is more specific to my question, but both options serve the same purpose.